# Transition from real to protected mode in the Linux kernel

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, real-mode, protected-mode

I am currently studying low level organization of operating systems. In order to achive that I am trying to understand how Linux kernel is loaded.

A thing that I cannot comprehend is the transition from 16-bit (real mode) to 32-bit (protected mode). It happens in [this file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/pmjump.S).

The `protected_mode_jump` function performs various auxiliary calculations for 32-bit code that is executed later, then enables `PE` bit in the `CR0` reguster

```
    movl    %cr0, %edx
    orb $X86_CR0_PE, %dl    # Protected mode
    movl    %edx, %cr0
```

and after that performs long jump to 32-bit code:

```
    # Transition to 32-bit mode
    .byte   0x66, 0xea      # ljmpl opcode
2:  .long   in_pm32         # offset
    .word   __BOOT_CS       # segment
```

As far as I understand `in_pm32` is the address of the 32-bit function which is declared right below the `protected_mode_jump`:

```
    .code32
    .section ".text32","ax"
GLOBAL(in_pm32)
    # some code
    # ...
    # some code
ENDPROC(in_pm32)
```

The `__BOOT_CS` sector base is 0 (the GDT is set beforehand [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/pm.c#L66)), so that means that offset should be basically absolute address of the `in_pm32` function.

That's the issue. During machine code generation the assembler/linker should not know the absolute address of the `in_pm32` function, because it does not know where it will be loaded in the memory in the real mode (various bootloaders can occupy various amounts of space, and the real mode kernel is loaded just after a bootloader).

Moreover, the linker script (`setup.ld` in the same folder) sets the origin of the code as 0, so seems like `in_pm32` address will be the offset from the beginning of the real mode kernel. It should work just fine with 16-bit code because `CS` register is set properly, but when long jump happens the CPU is already in protected mode, so a relative offset should not work.

So my question:
Why does the long jump in Protected Mode (`.byte    0x66, 0xea`) sets the proper code position if the offset (`.long    in_pm32`) is relative?

Seems like I am missing something really important.

Comment: I am about to head to bed as it is 3:30am. I only saw the part about the JMP. That jump is a 32-bit FAR JMP that sets the _CS_ selector. Setting the Protected Mode bit in CR0 actually puts you into a quasi 16-bit Protected Mode. To get into 32-bit protected mode you need to do a FAR JMP that takes a selector (__BOOT_CS) and an offset and jumps to it. __BOOT_CS should be a selector that points at a 32-bit code segment descriptor (likely with a base of 0 and limit of 0xffffffff) in the GDT. When that FAR JMP is complete it will be in 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: In essence that FAR JMP is required to get from quasi 16-bit protected mode to 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: Indeed, the `__BOOT_CS` selector base is 0. I suppose that it means that FAR JUMP should take the absolute address of desired function/label (because `0 + offset` will be just `offset`). But FAR JUMP here is called with relative offset (`.long    in_pm32` is the address of the `in_mp32` function from the beginning on the real mode kernel binary) - and I don't understand why at the end the `in_pm32` function is executed. The far jump should be mismatched on 0x7C00 + bootloader_size bytes.

Comment: After reviewing that code, I realized there is a step you are overlooking. First of all when compiled `2: .long in_pm32   # offset` will compute `in_pm32` relative to the beginning of the section in the linker script (which you seem to understand). That value changes at runtime with these instructions `movw %cs, %bx`
 `shll $4, %ebx`
 `addl %ebx, 2f` These instruction take the current _CS_ register and convert it into a linear address and that is added to the value AT label `2f`. `2f` is in fact this `2: .long in_pm32` . At runtime that offset is being adjusted before the JMP is made.

Comment: All that code was designed to be loaded into any real mode segment (relocatable). At runtime the _CS_ register is used to find the linear address (physical in this case) where the code is running and adjusts the address in that JMP so that it is no longer relative to the beginning of the segment, but relative to the bottom of memory (which in turn makes it an absolute address). The calculation from realmode segment:offset to linear address is (segment<<4)+offset . In this case it is (CS<<4)+in_pm32 and that value being saved back to label `2` in memory which is the FAR JMP itself.

Comment: You are right! I have overlooked that step. Rather, I have thought it does something for next stages of 32-bit code. I totally don't get used to a self modified code, so that trick is quite amazing for me.
I would be glad to accept your answer if you will post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that your question really is about how the offset stored at the following line can possibly work since it is relative to the start of the segment, not necessarily the start of memory:

```
 2:  .long   in_pm32         # offset
```

It is true that `in_pm32` is relative to the offset the [linker script](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/setup.ld) uses. In particular the linker script has:

```
. = 0;
.bstext     : { *(.bstext) }
.bsdata     : { *(.bsdata) }

. = 495;
.header     : { *(.header) }
.entrytext  : { *(.entrytext) }
.inittext   : { *(.inittext) }
.initdata   : { *(.initdata) }
__end_init = .;

.text       : { *(.text) }
.text32     : { *(.text32) }
```

The Virtual Memory Address is set to zero (and subsequently 495), so one would think that anything in the `.text32` section will have to be fixed in low memory. This would be a correct observation had it not been for these instructions in `protected_mode_jump`:

```
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    movw    %cs, %bx
    shll    $4, %ebx
    addl    %ebx, 2f

[snip]

    # Transition to 32-bit mode
    .byte   0x66, 0xea      # ljmpl opcode
2:  .long   in_pm32         # offset
    .word   __BOOT_CS       # segment
```

There is a manually encoded *FAR JMP* at the end that is used to set the *CS* selector to a 32-bit code descriptor to finalize the transition to 32-bit protected mode. But the key thing to observe are in these lines specifically:

```
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    movw    %cs, %bx
    shll    $4, %ebx
    addl    %ebx, 2f
```

This takes the value in *CS* and shifts it left by 4 bits (multiply by 16) and then adds it to the value stored at label `2f`. This is the way you take a [real mode segment:offset](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) pair and convert it into a linear address (which is the same as a physical address in this case). Label `2f` is in fact the offset `in_pm32` in this line:

```
2:  .long   in_pm32         # offset
```

When those instruction are complete, the long word value `in_pm32` in the *FAR JMP* will be adjusted (at run time) by adding the linear address of the current real mode code segment to the value `in_pm32`. This `.long` (DWORD) value will be replaced with (CS<<4)+in_pm32.

This code was designed to be relocatable to any real mode segment. The final linear address is computed at run time before the *FAR JMP*. This is in effect self-modifying code.